# Downloading PDF using AJAX (mPDF)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pdf

I am creating a three page form with calculations using JS in Wordpress. In the end I have to generate a PDF from that. I am using MPDF because it allows PDF from HTML code.
For that I made an ajax call (to admin-ajax.php in Wordpress) which downloads the file if I hit it directly. like if I paste URL

```
website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=generate_pdf
```

if downloads it whatever data it has.
But when I pass data to PHP using ajax, this ajax call returns some scrambled data in response because

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success : function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
})
```

I have seen many questions related to PDF and AJAX. But they are no use to me. 
Note: I don't want to use XHR, Please don't recommend using XHR,using Blob, using create ObjectUrl.. I have used them and they only download invalid or broke PDF files

Comment: Can you post the scrambled data response?

Comment: this is the part of the code 

`%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 2683>>
stream`

Comment: I think this is PDF's raw/binary data or some kind of that thing.